# R Capturing String inside Brackets

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to parse some of my chess pgn data but I'm having some trouble capturing  characters just inside one bracket.

```
testString <- '[Event \"?\"]\n[Site \"http://www.chessmaniac.com play free chess\"]\n[Date \"2018.08.25\"]\n[Round \"-\"]\n[White \"NothingFancy 1497\"]\n[Black \"JR Smith 1985\"]\n[Result \"1-0\"]\n\n1.'

#Attempt to just get who white is, which is inside a bracket [White xxx]

findWhite <- regexpr('\\[White.*\\]', tempString)

regmatches(tempString, findWhite)
```

The stringr package seems to do what I want, but I'm curious what is different about the use of the same regular expression.  I'm fine using stringr, but I like to also know how to do this in base R.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(tempString, '\\[White.*\\]')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the whole match starting with `[White` and ending with `]` you may use

```
regmatches(testString, regexpr("\\[White\\s*[^][]*]", testString))
[1] "[White \"NothingFancy 1497\"]"
```

If you only need the substring inside double quotes:

```
regmatches(testString, regexpr("\\[White\\s*\\K[^][]*", testString, perl=TRUE))
[1] "\"NothingFancy 1497\""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOJXmv/2).

To strip the double quotes, you may use something like

```
regmatches(testString, regexpr('\\[White\\s*"\\K.*(?="])', testString, perl=TRUE))
[1] "NothingFancy 1497"
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOJXmv/3)  and an [online R demo](https://ideone.com/GDP8qo).

**Details**

- `\\[` - a `[` char
- `White`  - a literal substring
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\K` -  [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discarding the text matched so far
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `.*` (in the other version) - matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?="])` - a positive lookahead that matches a position inside a string that is immediately followed with `"]`.

Answer (score 1):

At least one way to do it in base R is to use `sub` and only keep the part that you want.

```
sub(".*\\[White\\s(*.*?)\\].*", "\\1", testString)
[1] "\"NothingFancy 1497\""
```